# Converting character code to character C# using CultureInfo

Tags: c#, globalization, cultureinfo

I'm using **Arabic** `CultureInfo` in a C# project. At one place I'm converting the character code to character using `Strings.Chr(chrCode)` if the language which I select is **English** it is *working fine*, other than English it is returning some *special characters*.

If I choose **Arabic** `CultureInfo` it is returning *Arabic characters* instead of English characters.

Please suggest me how to get English characters when I choose other `CultureInfo`.

Comment: The Chr() function is legacy, used 20+ years ago when the OS was not yet Unicode at its core, programs still used 8-bit characters and code pages were still common.  Today you must use ChrW() and AscW().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [Win-1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256) code page ([Strings.Chr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chr(v=vs.110).aspx) *doesn't work* with Unicode, but with code pages)?

```
// From arabic letter Ḍād to its one byte code (Win-1256)
byte code = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes("\u0636")[0];
// From code back to arabic letter 
char back = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetString(new byte[] { code })[0];

Console.WriteLine($"{back} == {code} (\\u{(int)back:x4})");
```

If you want to wrap it into a method:

```
private static char ArabicChr(int chrCode) {
  if (chrCode < byte.MinValue || chrCode > byte.MaxValue)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
      "chrCode",
     $"chrCode must be in [{byte.MinValue}..{byte.MaxValue}] range");

  return Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetString(new byte[] { (byte)chrCode })[0];
}
```

Outcome:

```
ض == 214 (\u0636)
```

**Edit**: If you want to obtain *English* characters, you can try using *Win-1252* code page:

```
private static char EnglishChr(int chrCode) {
  if (chrCode < byte.MinValue || chrCode > byte.MaxValue)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
      "chrCode",
     $"chrCode must be in [{byte.MinValue}..{byte.MaxValue}] range");

  return Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(new byte[] { (byte)chrCode })[0];
}
```

In *general case*, if you have culture's name, e.g. `"en-US"`:

```
private static char Chr(int chrCode, string cultureName = "en-US") {
  if (chrCode < byte.MinValue || chrCode > byte.MaxValue)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
      "chrCode",
     $"chrCode must be in [{byte.MinValue}..{byte.MaxValue}] range");

  int page = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureName).TextInfo.ANSICodePage;

  return Encoding.GetEncoding(page).GetString(new byte[] { (byte)chrCode })[0];
}
```

Comment: @Abhishek Hotte: if you want *English* characters when workring with Arabic culture, you should use `1252` code page (see my edit)